# Save arguments/variables to discord account in JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm new here and I want to assign username for e.g on execute command !register 'username' save it to json file with assigned discord tag/user id and next make command that uses argument 'username' from before saved file it is possile on Node.js? I don't wanna to use sql because it's blackmagic for me and I don't have time for it right now.

Comment: you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf, which has easy api and also handles atomic writes via https://github.com/fabiospampinato/atomically

Comment: if you don't have time for sql, you why do you have time for asking others to code for you? The easiest way (and most efficient)  would be to use MongoDB or SQLite - two well-documented and easily understandable programs. As mentioned below, JSON will cause huge problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use JSON (I highly recommend AGAINST that, I've done it myself and I very often had to deal with my JSON's being completely wiped). use the `fs` package that comes with Node.

set the file as a blank array and this code will work.

```js
var username = message.content.split(" ")[1];

var oldJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./usersfile.json");
var newJSON = oldJSON.push(`{"username": ${username}, "userID": ${message.member.id}, "name": ${message.member.username}, "discriminator": ${message.member.discriminator}}`)

fs.writeFileSync(JSON.stringify(newJSON), "./usersfile.json");
```

Again, I HIGHLY recommend AGAINST using this system as it's incredibly bug prone. Just learn MySQL or MongoDB. But if you're willing to take (the immense) risk, that should work.

Comment: yea it works but how to assign it to discord tag/user id?

Comment: @LixerMan I've edited it, it now puts "username" as whatever the input on the command is, userID is the user's actual ID, name is the users username, and discriminator is their unique 4 char discriminator.

Comment: for e.g when i want to add username from JSON file to this?

 ```const pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, "test", there put username + ".png")```

and i want only before registred member can use "registred username" this not all users.

Comment: Well PNG is an image file, I'm not sure what you mean there at all.

Comment: i mean i want to rename example.png and it's automaticly assigned when someone type !give 'some arg' and it renames it to  'username'.png  (saved username in JSON).

Comment: @LixerMan ```fs.renameSync('/path/to/original.png', `/path/to/${username}.png`)```